# Regex: Match only if string A is found and string B is not

Tags: regex

I need this to be a single regex because it goes in a Google search appliance's "do not crawl" list.  (I believe Google regular expressions are similar to GNU regular expressions.) So I also do not have the option of using code (in any language) instead.

This question has been asked before but the answers have usually been code rather than regex.

What I want to do is match a string if it contains the substring aaa ONLY IF IT DOES NOT ALSO CONTAIN the substring bbb.

As a more specific example: I want to match if a string contains "/RFA/" but ONLY if it does NOT contain "Google=yes".

So:  "blahblah/RFA/index.cfm?Review=1&blahblah" should match.

But: "blahblah/RFA/index.cfm?Review=1&Google=yes&blahblah" should fail.

By the way, if it simplifies things any, when it is present the bbb substring will always be after the aaa substring.

Comment: You just need negative lookahead and lookbehind, searching for "bbb" at any point in the string on either side.

Comment: @Neil I'm not sure the base GNU Regexes support lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: Then it is impossible to do.  Lookahead and lookbehinds make it possible to capture values within the context of its surroundings.  The alternative would be to capture the entire expression unless capture groups are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The only sane way to do this is `/foo/ && !/bar/`. There are other less sanitary approaches, however.

```
/^ (?= (?!NOPAT) . )* $ ) YESPAT /xs
```

Comment: /foo/ && !/bar/ expresses exactly what I'm trying to achieve, however, your solution does not match in the Google pattern tester (look-ahead not supported in GNU regex?)

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Not Valid for GNU regex, just a fix for Jonathan's post**

@Jonathan. That won't work because the .* will capture greedily to the end of the line, and then only then try to look for `Google=yes`. So it won't ever match the `Google=yes`.

This modification will work better:

```
/^.*\/RFA\/(?!.*Google=yes)/
```

See: http://codepad.org/hohjsdeI

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
/^.*\/RFA\/(?!.*Google=yes)/
```

This is using a negative look-ahead, which may or may not be supported by your regex engine.

=========================================================================

EDIT:

I think we've seen enough evidence to say your regex engine doesn't do look aheads. So the only other way I can think of is to do 2 tests:

```
/\/RFA\//
```

and

/Google=yes/

and the acceptable condition is TEST1 && !TEST2, which will have to be done by your code comparing the results of the tests. Not as clean, but it gets the job done.

Comment: That won’t work.  The not part might be hiding at the beginning.

Comment: In my case the **not** part is always after the required part, however, it still does not appear to work.

Comment: @Mike: It can’t work **because he forgot to quantify the *not* portion.** See my answer for what I mean.

Comment: @tchrist: Ah, yes, per Jacob's suggested correction, I've moved the `.*` inside the `()`.

Comment: @Mike: Look aheads may not be supported by your regex engine, as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: `.*(?!Google=yes).*` is functionally the same as writing `.*`. Suppose you test it against the string `foo&Google=yes&bar`. The first `.*` will match all the way to the end of the line, since `foo&Google=yes&bar` is not *followed* by `Google=yes`; it merely *contains* it. Even if you changed it to `(.(?!Google=yes))*.*` it still wouldn't work, since the `(.(?!Google=yes))*` part would match `foo`, and the `.*` part would continue matching until the end of the line.

Comment: @Jonathan - I've tested the revised version in the Google pattern tester and it does not match. So it seems that you are right & the Google regex doesn't support look-ahead. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Jonathan (& others) since this is a Google search appliance, the only option I have is to add regex's to its do-not-crawl pattern list - there's no way to run code on the device, so I'm back to square 1.  But I do want to thank all of you for trying - you guys are outstanding!